# Why final key word can guarantee safe publication if constructor is not synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

The book **Java Concurrency in Practice** mentions that

A properly constructed object can be safely published by:

```
Storing a reference to it into a final field of a properly constructed object
```

Firstly, I thought because a **final** field can only be initilized in the class constructor and Java constructor is implicitly "**Synchronized**". However, I realized that this is not the case.

```
class Student{
   int student_id;
   public Student(int i){
       student_id = i;
   }
}

class Test {
   private final Student student;
   public Test(){
         student = new Student(1);
         ...
   }
}
```

For example, the above code how can JVM guarantee **student** is a safe publication?

What about it is a **static final**?

```
class Test {
       private static final Student student;
       public Test(){
             student = new Student(1); //will this be partially constructed when the other thread reads a bad object ?

             ...
       }
    }
```

Does **final** itself imply something so that Jave Memory Model will guarantee the same publication ?

Comment: Your last snippet wouldn't compile.

Comment: Yes, i just realized that static final filed must be initialized at class loading time rather than the time when creating a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

> JVM guarantee student is a safe publication?

There is a number of ways to ensure safe publication, usually using a write barrier will be enough. In any case, however the JVM it is must guarantee this for the processor it is running on.

> What about it is a static final?

All static field are initialised in a single threaded manner. Class initialisation is thread safe whether you use final or not.

> Does final itself imply something so that Jave Memory Model will guarantee the same publication ?

Except for constructors, not really. It is easier to support safe publication of a value which should not change.

Comment: I think the part I am confused is that in the constructor when execute this line student = new Student(1), is that possible that new Student(1) is partially constructed and the other thread reads a bad object since the constructor is not synchronized?

Comment: @GuifanLi this can happen if the field is not final and the object is passed between threads without using a write barrier.

Comment: So why final in constructor can guarantee the safe publication? What does final tells JMM?

Comment: @GuifanLi the JMM says they have to be published safely. This is not as a consequence of something else but a direct requirement. Note before Java 5.0 it didn't do this.